# Zsh: string getting expanded

Tags: zsh

I am trying to create a Zsh version of the Command Line Window in Vim.

I want to use the `moreutils` program `vipe` to pipe history into.

For that purpose, I have something like:

```
EDITOR='nvim -c "normal G"'      
fc -ln | vipe
```

Here, `fc -ln` represents the history, and `$EDITOR` represents the program that I'll be piping into.

The problem is, the above does not work.

In this specific case I get the file `G"` opened. It seems that the double quotes to surround the command are not being recognized.

Nor could I get it to work with any other combination of single quotes, double quotes or variables.

How can I pass in the string `"normal G"`?

Answer (score 0):

`vipe` [splits its arguments by space](https://github.com/madx/moreutils/blob/5ca552dd82dc3ef5ee0d388716148c5a653b72bb/vipe#L66), so it is not possible to use multi-word `c` options. I resolved this by creating a `.vim` file and using `nvim -S file.vim`.